# LeafletJS: Load Tile Layer based on bounding box

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I have a LeafletJS map application with lots of layers. I have a few layers that only have imagery for certain regions across the world. Because everything goes on a world base map. All tile caches are generated as standard tile caches covering the world in web Mercator (Google tile cache system) and are served using a ArcGIS Server.

Here is what I would like to do: Load a tile layer when certain bounding box comes into active view and then unload it when box is out.

Is there a simple way to do this in LeafletJS without going through manual geometry check ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I solved it. `L.tileLayer` does accept bounds parameter. I found it by digging into the code, but it is currently missing from the documentation. This fixed it .

```
L.tileLayer(config.ISLAND_IMAGERY + '/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
                zIndex: -4,
                subdomains: ['', '1', '2'],
                bounds:[
                    new L.LatLng(15.292019,145.834236),
                    new L.LatLng(15.097866,145.676994)
                ]
            }),
```

Answer (score 1):

TiledMapLayer in [esri-leaflet](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet#tiledmaplayer) seems to handle diplaying cached ArcGIS Server tiles only where they are present without writing any code pretty seamlessly.

(pan this [example app](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/demographicmaps.html) north into Canada to stop loading US Demographic layers)

are the 1KB request/responses in other areas problematic?

Comment: I agree, but my layers are not always esri. Anyway, I found a solution. Apparently L.tileLayer does accept bounds param, only it is not listed in documentation. Thanks for your answer. great tip!